# Find unique set of elements among lists stored as elements of RDD

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My RDD `all_keys` stores lists of values:

```
>> all_keys.take(3)
[['a','b','c'],
 ['a','b'],
 ['a','d','f']]
```

Most of those values are recurring, but there are some lists that do have values not present in other lists.

How do i get a list of unique elements from all the lists stored in the RDD?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to flatMap your RDD to transform it from an RDD of lists of strings to a RDD of strings. Then, you can use the `distinct()` method to return only the unique strings.

Create data

```
all_keys = [['category', 'ser_id', 'appname', 'timestamp', 'label', 'ser_token', 'appver', 'action'],
     ['category', 'ser_id', 'appname', 'timestamp', 'vale', 'label', 'ser_token', 'appver', 'action', 'type'], 
     ['category', 'ser_id', 'appname', 'timestamp', 'vale', 'label', 'ser_token', 'appver', 'type' ]]
rdd = sc.parallelize(all_keys)
```

Define flatMap function

```
def explode(row):
    for k in row:
        yield k
```

Flatmap, get distinct elements, collect

```
rdd.flatMap(explode).distinct().collect()
```

Results

> ['category',
>    'ser_id',
>    'type',
>    'action',
>    'timestamp',
>    'ser_token',
>    'appver',
>    'vale',
>    'label',
>    'appname']

Answer (score -1):

If you mean remove duplicates in your final list (there are no duplicates in your example)

```
list(set(all_keys.take(3)))
```

If you mean remove duplicate entries for one key in your rdd, e.g. 'a' use

```
all_keys.distinct(lambda row:row[0])
```